# jQuery when, then executing in browser but not on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Following code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'actions.xml',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function(data) {
    $(data).find('script').each(function() {
        deferreds.push($.ajax({
            url: $(this).text(),
            dataType: 'script'
        }));
    });

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        $('.preloader').fadeOut();
        ...
    });
});
```

On the browser, this code executes without a problem. The preloader fades out and everything is fine. On a mobile project via cordova, I get a problem. The `$.when.apply` part doesn't seem to execute. The preloader is never fading out and because of this the app is not working. Does anyone know, why this is happening?

The deferreds array has the same values as in the browser. I tested this via `alert(JSON.stringify(deferreds));`

I have figured this out by setting some alerts and could come down to this specific problem. It is definitely crashing at this point.

I have to finish this thing due today and I tried different things like setting timeouts, putting other things in function, etc, to solve this, but nothing seems to work and maybe an expert in this has the solution in two seconds.

Comment: Are you setting `$.when` outside first ajax `done()` callback? If ya, `deferreds` should be empty array, right?! I would set it just after `each` loop

Comment: It is inside the .done part of the ajax function. I also alerted JSON.stringify(deferreds) between the data.find and the $.when and it has the same values as in the browser version, so this worked

Comment: Oh ya, get fooled by your not complete posted code and bad indentation

Comment: Yeah idk, when i copy it from sublime it indents the next lines but not the first one...

Comment: I suspect some of ur deferred is not resolved on mobile, have u try to inspect individual defer status?

Comment: Ya, try using `fail()/always()`, and check errors. But this part looks really suspicious to me `url: $(this).text(),` regarding getting js script. It should be `url: this.src,` but as you say it work on desktop browsers, well...  EDIT: oops; you are targeting XML, forget my last comment part then

Comment: On which part should I put the deferred.always()?  Between the data.find and the $.when?

Comment: @FrederikWitte Instead of `then()` but you could simply adding error callback to `then()`: `.then(successHandler, errorHandler);` and check if `errorHandler` is fired. BTW, how many requests are sending in parallel? Maybe mobile browser just abort some of them if too many

Comment: Ah okay! Now I added an error callback and just alerted 'failed' and it really gets to the error callback. I really don't know so much about the when then thing, how would I now debug this? To figure out what I can do? Thank you so much guys!

Comment: It's not really the mobile browser, it's an UI Web View, as I created this app with cordova, I don't know if it's the same as you meant

Comment: @FrederikWitte I guess it is because too many requests in parallel, so check error message and maybe try running them one by one, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Lvt1hn/

Comment: The big problem here is, that the iOS simulator is not showing any console.logs , nor javascript error messages. So the only way i can debug this is, by alerting stuff

Comment: Oh my god, it works!!! @A.Wolff could you write this as an answer? Just using the "one by one" method made it work! Wow, thank you so so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid sending too many requests at same time but one by one using this kind of logic:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'actions.xml',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function (data) {
    var queue = $.Deferred().resolve();
    $(data).find('script').map(function () {
        return $(this).text()
    }).get().forEach(function (url) {
        queue = queue.then(function () {
            return $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'script'
            }).promise();
        })
    });
});
```

Be aware, maybe your issue is just because IOS simulator, you should test your original code on an IOS device (if not already done), and see if same issue persists.

Comment: Thanks, sir! I tested the said code also on my iPad for both codes, and it broke with my code and works with yours :) Should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Okay there seems to be a problem with that, too. I don't know how I should debug this, but now all these scripts which are loading dynamically are not working on iPad, on browser it works like a charm. The 'standard' scripts from the index.html work, but these are not doing anything. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @FrederikWitte Just to be sure, if you load these scripts synchronously (meaning using synchronous ajax requests), are they working as expected on iPad? Can you provide sample of a script failing? And iPad browser must have a console you should check for error. I don't have iPad but you should find easily resources online as how to debug js on iPad

Comment: Hey, the script is not working when I use synchronous requests. The console doesn't say anything. I debugged it with the developer tools in safari and opened the app in an iOS simulator(also tested on ipad, not working...). The script is not "failing" the script isnt loading at all. I inserted some alerts and they execute in the browser, but not on iPad, so that and the fact that none of the functionality works, shows me, that it's not working :/